# How to apply media query to email send from backend?

Tags: css, node.js, media-queries

I am sending emails from my backend (Node) and added media queries, so that different content is shown when email is opened on the phone vs desktop. The media query is applied correctly when email is opened on a native app (lets say yahoo native app) on phone but NOT when opened on not native mobile app /when i open yahoo mail from google etc. on phone.

Why is that? How can I fix the media query?

```
<head>
 <style>
     a[class=desktopLink] {
         ...
     }
       
     @media (max-device-width: 480px) {
      a[class=mobileLink] {
      display: flex !important;
      ...
       }
     a[class=desktopLink] {
       display: none !important;
     }
     }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div>
 <a class="mobileLink" style="display:none;>Account Activation MOBILE</a>
 <a class="desktopLink">Account Activation Desktop</a> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Lets understand the issue? Do we have either a) Inconsistency Across Clients: Email clients have varied levels of support for CSS and media queries? b) Viewport vs. Device Width issue: The max-device-width media query targets the physical device's width, which might not be the same as the viewport's width in a web browser.

Maybe it works if you use "max-width" Instead of "max-device-width." Example:

```
@media (max-width: 480px) {
    a[class=mobileLink] {
        display: flex !important;
        /* other styles */
    }
    a[class=desktopLink] {
        display: none !important;
    }
}
```

or it is so that some email clients give priority to inline styles. Ensure that your default styles are inlined, and then use "!important" in your media queries to override.